# Накрутка голосов в плагине ExtraVote

Tags: joomla, php, плагин

Как известно, в Joomla 2.5 есть дефолтный плагин оценки статей - Content - ExtraVote. Возникла небольшая проблема, в накручивании голосов. Т.е. после оценки можно еще раз оценивать.

Подробнее о проблеме: скажем, есть 1ПК / 2ПК, у каждого разные IP. После оценки статьи первым ПК материал оценивает 2ПК - в сумме 2 голоса. И после оценки 2ПК снова можно оценивать материал Первому ПК - в сумме 3 голоса. После первого - второй может оценивать и так далее.

Как можно прикрыть данный баг?
Например, 1IP и 1ПК = 1 Голос.